# systemd-timesyncd always restarted once got Router Advertisement

Tags: system-clock

On raspberry pi os, pi zeor 2 w, the `systemd-timesyncd` always restat once received Router Advertisement from router

The messages are like following:

```
Nov 28 12:22:46 raspberrypi dhcpcd[837]: wlan0: Router Advertisement from fe80::925c:44ff:XXXX:XXXX
Nov 28 12:22:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Network Time Synchronization...
Nov 28 12:22:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Succeeded.
Nov 28 12:22:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
Nov 28 12:22:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Nov 28 12:22:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Nov 28 12:22:47 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[8816]: Initial synchronization to time server 172.105.75.114:123 (0.pool.ntp.org).
Nov 28 12:24:55 raspberrypi dhcpcd[837]: wlan0: Router Advertisement from fe80::925c:44ff:XXXX:XXXX
Nov 28 12:24:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Network Time Synchronization...
Nov 28 12:24:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Succeeded.
Nov 28 12:24:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
Nov 28 12:24:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Nov 28 12:24:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Nov 28 12:24:56 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[8856]: Initial synchronization to time server 193.175.73.20:123 (0.pool.ntp.org).
```

Any idea what could be the problems? Thanks very much!

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: Sorry I am not an expert with pi or systemd-timesyncd? Is it expected to restart so often?

Comment: I see the same behaviour. It looks like there was [an old systemd bug that triggered something very similar](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87505), but that was fixed some time in 2015, in a version long before any of the versions used on Raspberry Pi OS. I'm a bit baffled about why this seems to only be hitting Pis, given I'd thought all the relevant bits of code here were common to Debian, but that definitely seems to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me like a bug in the dhcpcd5 "hook" scripts. It's being tracked in the Debian bug tracker at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1008059.

In the meantime, you can work around it by either (a) taking the patch I've proposed in that bug report, or (b) by disabling the reload of systemd-timesyncd, such as by running the below one-liner:

```
sudo sed -i 's/systemctl try-restart systemd-timesyncd\.service/:/' /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/64-timesyncd.conf
```

(the one-liner above will disable this behaviour unconditionally, where the patch will check if it's actually needed; if you might manually change the configured SNTP server, you probably want the full patch not this quick fix.)

Comment: Thank you! P.S. To everyone reading this, the bug was fixed in version dhcpcd5/9.4.1-2 so avoid making changes to configuration files. Update dhcpcd instead.